# Firewalld and iptables priority

Tags: iptables, firewall, firewalld

Simple question: What is the priority if we have both firewalld and iptables in use? Which takes the priority in the rules.

For example, if I block ICMP with firewalld and with iptables I accept it, what happens?

Comment: According to `firewalld` [documentation](https://firewalld.org/documentation/concepts.html) : it relies on iptables (or others) to implement its firewalling capabilities. In the end, you would have only 1 set of `iptables` rules, either directly generated from `firewalld` or manually modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewalld [uses](https://firewalld.org/documentation/concepts.html) iptables to implement its rules. If require some iptables features not implemented in firewalld, you can configure iptables [rules directly in firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/direct/options.html) . Using more than one tool to manage iptables rules might otherwise cause problems.

Iptables rules are evaluated in order, processing for a packet stops on first matching rule. Using your example: if you accept the icmp as the first rule in `INPUT` chain, the packet will be accepted even if there is a later drop rule, since it will not get evaluated. Similarly if you add accept at the end of the chain and there is an earlier (firewalld generated) rule to drop it, the packet will be dropped.